# Можно ли в tkinter работать со звуком и видео

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, видео, mp4

Можно ли в tkinter работать со звуком и видео?
Типа открываешь окно, выбираешь файл mp4 и он воспроизводится в окне, и чтобы можно было прокручивать вперед или назад. Посоветуйте статьи. Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-graphics/thread2464084.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю встроить в окно фрейм от pygame https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464185/2101808

Потом запустить на нем видео https://stackoverflow.com/a/21356810/2101808